# RotateControl not getting displayed in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Here is the relevant code:

```
  var map;
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523);
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        panControl: true,
        rotateControl: true,
        rotateControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },  
        center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
```

I tried mapTypeId of HYBRID too. I tried disabling/enabling rotateControl, panControl, rotateControlOptions, etc. The Map shows with pancontrol but without rotate control. If relevant, here is the div markup:

```
 <div id="map-canvas" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:100px;width:800px;height:500px;
   border:red 2px solid;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;
   border-radius: 10px;"></div>
```

Included the styles inline here just for brevity in presenting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with zoom:20.
You need to zoom to see your position closely. Then you'll see the Rotation Control

Answer (score 3):

If zoom doesn't help then enabling of `rotateControl` won't either if there is no 45° imagery for specific place.

**rotateControl** *enables/disables the appearance of a Rotate control for controlling the orientation of 45° imagery. By default, the control's appearance is determined by the presence or absence of 45° imagery for the given map type at the current zoom and location. You may alter the control's behavior by setting the map's rotateControlOptions to specify the RotateControlOptions to use (**though you cannot make the control appear if no 45° imagery is currently available**).*